# Matplotlib many subplots xtick labels intercepting

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I'm plotting many subplots in the same figure. I encounter the problem that xtick labels intercept one with each other. I do not want any space between the subplots.
Here is an example: 
[image: Example with squares and lines]

In particular I would like xtick labels not to be above/below the green lines, just like it happens at the points indicated with red squares.
One idea I had so far was, in a case where my max=4 and min=0, I'd draw tick labels for 1 2 and 3 at their respective locations, e.g 1,2,3. Then I'd draw 4 at the position 3.8 and 0 at the position 0.2. Any ideas? 
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you asked for, but a quick solution is to set the alignment parameter:

```
pylab.xticks(..., horizontalalignment='left')
pylab.yticks(..., verticalalignment='bottom')
```

This will apply to all ticks.

Comment: damn, that's so close! one-sided solution, thanks for the insight.

Comment: Yeah -- I personally prefer all the ticks to be aligned the same way. It feels "neater". With one single tick out of position, I would feel a bit uncomfortable. But that's just personal preference. Another option is simply to remove tick "0" altogether from the x-axis and remove ticks "4" and "8" from the y-axis. Their values can be inferred from the others; their absence does not really detract from the graph. I think Edward Tufte would agree. :) http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
axScatter.set_xticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6])
axScatter.set_yticks([-8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6])
```

And you can use:

```
axScatter.yaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)
```

To make the y axis labels disappear for the top right and bottom right plots.

Answer (score 0):

The whole plt.figure routine should look something like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()

axplot_topleft = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
axplot_topleft.xaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)
axplot_topleft.set_yticks([-8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6])

axplot_topright = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
axplot_topright.xaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)
axplot_topright.yaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)

axplot_bottomleft = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
axplot_bottomleft.set_xticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6])
axplot_bottomleft.set_yticks([-8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6])

axplot_bottomright = fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)
axplot_bottomright.yaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)
axplot_bottomright.set_xticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6])
```